# Change attribute value of a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some tags like this:

```
<path d="M 782.5 421 C 787.828 421 787.828 429 782.5 429 C 777.172 429 777.172 421 782.5 421 Z"
fill="#4572A7" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.000001" width="8" height="8"></path>
```

And I want for all the  tags to have bigger width and height instead of 8. But I'm confused because they aren't in the style attribute. How to change them via javascript or jquery?

Comment: read [jQuery.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: you could do this without jquery by just changing the `width` and `height` values in your tag to say something like Matt Ball posted. `height="16"` and `width="16"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('path').attr({width: 16, height: 16})
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the attr function of jquery like this.

```
$('path').attr('height','55');
```

the first parameter is the name of the attribute, the second one is the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $(function (){

    $('path').attr({width:12, height:12})

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
  $("path").attr("width","150");
```